# How to write a test to test a twig template

Tags: codeception, craftcms

I would like to know if there is a way with Codeception to write a test that would test logic on a twig template in isolation similar to "component" testing in framework such as JEST. To give you more context we have a Craft CMS website that is built with matrix blocks that are re-used on multiple pages. We would like to write test suite that test all those matrix blocks in isolation. I believe functional tests is what we need, but I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Functional tests don't test in isolation, they execute entire application.

Isolated test would be a unit test that initializes Twig and calls render method.

Based on https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/intro.html#basic-api-usage

```
public function testTemplate()
{
   $loader = ...;
   $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);

   $rendered = $twig->render('template', $vars);
   $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $rendered);
}
```